# How to fix mongoose type issue with ObjectID?

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, docker, mongoose

**What is the current behavior?**

I have an issue while building the node application on docker. It was building fine before but since last Friday ( 30/07/2021 ), I got the issues with mongodb. Building the application in my local environment is fine. The issue is just from the docker build.

[image]

**Steps to reproduce.**

I just run this command to build the app on docker:
`docker-compose build && docker-compose up -d`

*docker-compose.yml*

```
...
mongo:
    image: "mongo:4.2"
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - ./data/mongo:/data/db
    restart: always
...
```

*Dockerfile*

```
FROM node:14
COPY . .
RUN npm install --production && npm run build
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

*tsbase.json*

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "target": "ES2017"
  }
}
```

*tsconfig.json*

```
{
  "extends": "./tsbase",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dst"
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

**What is the expected behavior?**

It should build fine on docker.

**What are the versions of Node.js, Mongoose, and MongoDB you are using? Note that "latest" is not a version.**

Node `14`

Mongoose `^4.11.8`

MongoDB `4.2`

@types/mongoose `^4.7.21`

> I found that [mongo:4.2](https://hub.docker.com/layers/mongo/library/mongo/4.2/images/sha256-9ed8cbdf7f6fe44b3671e34501c1e137347481ec156cfa54f01afec5d882b270?context=explore) image was updated 6 days ago on docker hub. In addition, I am on Mac

Can you please help me with this bug? Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have anything concrete, but I have faced similar issues before and this is due to incompatible package versions between mongoose & types/mongoose (I think types/mongoose?). My only suggestion is to play with package versions until you resolve the issue.

Comment: guess it has to do with mongo types being deprecated here-didnt yet solve it tho:https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/mongodb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issue by adding @types/mongodb to my project.

Here's the [link](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/10532#issuecomment-891173320) for the details.